# Not able to load an unpacked edge extension, due to strange errors. How to fix that?

Tags: microsoft-edge, manifest.json, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to load a half-made extension, to see if it works.

I have made the manifest file, and a few more files to test my extension to see if it works as expected.

the manifest:
[image: manifest file]

but, I instead receive a strange error from edge.

[image: edge not allowing extension to load by putting up strange errors_updated]
I am putting an extension to load which looks error-free. This error would limit my extension to do nothing at all when I click on the button, if extensions with errors were allowed.

Can anyone take a close look at the manifest, and recommend changes? thanks.

note: This did not happen with chrome. I was looking forward to post my extension there, but instead went for edge, because I think edge has lesser extensions than chrome.
Also, making .json files require a programming head. I have that but just an unexpected error appeared. Dont ask to take from the internet, it simply can‘t give answers related to the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste your manifest into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. I can see a missing comma for description.